# Displaying Content of first file from directory in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to display the first file saved in the directory into ContentRichText(display window).

I have one directory named output in path C:\Setup\output.
In output folder there are multiple files generated which are dynamic always.

Suppose the files in output folder are a.txt, b.txt, c.txt
So I want to auto display the content of 1st file of output folder i.e. a.txt into display window.

I tried but that is the static way but i want to know how to display the first file always in dynamic way as the file will not be with name "a.txt"

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Setup\output\a.txt");
ContentRichText.Text = content;
```

Can anyone suggest how can i do that.

Comment: What is the "first file"? The first file created? Or the file with the first name in alphabetical sorting? Or?

Comment: Define "first" file? According to what criteria? Once you've sorted that, `Directory.GetFiles` plus some `OrderBy` is all you need.

Comment: Please use the "visual-studio" tag only for questions relating to the development environment itself, not for question about programming *with* Visual Studio.

Comment: @KlausGütter   the file is not sorted... number of files are generated through script and they i am storing it into output folder. I want to auto display the first text file generated in display.

Comment: @sonali: So you want the file with the earliest creation date?

Comment: @Alejandro i am not ordering its storing all generated filles into output folder automatically. I want to display the first created file in the list.

Comment: Please understand that the files in a folder have no intrinsic ordering, it is just a bunch of files. So "first file" has no meaning per se, you have to define a specific ordering to make sense of "first"

Comment: @BenVoigt script is generating all the text file at a time and keeping it into output folder. I want to show one file automatically the top most one

Comment: @KlausGütter yes correct so i can say the top most in the list of files

Comment: Sorry, you still did not get it. Whether you say "top most" or "first" does not matter. You need to define the criterion by which to sort.

Answer (score 1):

If the "first file" is the file with the oldest creation date:

```
var firstFile = new DirectoryInfo(myFolder).GetFiles("*.txt")
    .OrderBy(info => info.CreationTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

or the oldest modification date:

```
var firstFile = new DirectoryInfo(myFolder).GetFiles("*.txt")
    .OrderBy(info => info.LastWriteTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or if it is the "alphabetically first file":

```
var firstFile = new DirectoryInfo(myFolder).GetFiles("*.txt")
    .OrderBy(info => info.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `GetFiles()`, followed by `FirstOrDefault()`, will return a `FileInfo` instance, so that is what the type of `firstFile` will be (or it will be null if there were no files; something you should check for).  You'd access the full path to the file with `firstFile.FullName`.